# UI notifications and events for object tag / activex control?

Tags: internet-explorer, activex

I currently have an ActiveX control deployed to my users as such:

```
<OBJECT 
  ID="ActiveXControl" WIDTH=350 HEIGHT=50 
  CODEBASE="http://www.mysite.com/activexcontrol.cab" 
  CLASSID="CLSID:12345678-1234-1234-1234-111111222222"> 
</OBJECT>
```

Deployment in this manner allows self-registration.  The user typically gets the yellow bar (or white popup box at the bottom, in the case of IE9) asking for permission to install.  If the user grants permission, IE refreshes the page, then appears to actually download the control from the CODEBASE location.  At the completion of the CAB download, then a UAC prompt is typically displayed to the user.

The problem I'm having is that my control is 500 KB which is slow to download for some users.  They authorize my control (via the yellow IE bar) but then their browser sits there while it downloads the control, and they think nothing is happening, so they refresh the page (bad) or leave (worse).  I need to have some sort of progress meter or some sort of "please wait" message that disappears AFTER the control is done loading.

To sum it up, there are currently 3 stages:

1. ActiveX deployment page (user has not authorized)
2. ActiveX deployment page (user has authorized, and IE has refreshed the page)
3. Control has fully downloaded and is running

(remember that stages 1 and 2 will be the same server code, same HTTP GET, and my server will not know the difference.)

The problem for me is that the UI is the same for all 3 stages.  How can I communicate to the user what is happening? I have tried an approach where I put a "please wait" message on the page, but this has two drawbacks

- it doesn't make sense for stage 1.  The user doesn't have to wait.  They need to authorize the control.
- I can't make the "please wait" message disappear once I reach stage 3.  I tried to put an onload attribute for the OBJECT tag to use some JS to erase the message but IE doesn't seem to obey it.

Any suggestions?